# Running GWT Speedtracer without Jetty

Tags: java, gwt, jetty, gwt2

We are trying to run the GWT (2.1) Speedtracer, but have trouble with it, since Jetty doesn't accept our JDBC resources (they work fine in Tomcat) - probably because the JAR containing the drivers is not found by it.

Is there a way to make the GWT speedtracer run without the Jetty Server?

Or how do I make the web.xml/context.xml compatible with both Tomcat and Jetty?

I would prefer to run it in Jetty - as long as this won't cause problems with tomcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want to use Tomcat:**

The GWT documentation [mentions](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/server-side-tracing.html), that you can use Speed Tracer on the server-side with the SpringSource tc Server (which is a Tomcat server).

**If you want to use Jetty:**

Using DataSources with the embedded GWT Jetty server is possible, but not easy. It's explained in this [Google Group post](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/3f5369b0aea1a265) for GWT 1.6. I have tried this with GWT 2.1, and it basically remains the same procedure. Here's a quick outline:

- enable JNDI for the embedded Jetty:

  - add `jetty-naming-*.jar`, `jetty-plus-*.jar`
  - modify the JettyLauncher,
  - add the VM arg `-Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.mortbay.naming.InitialContextFactory` (or use jndi.properties)
- create a jetty-env.xml (similar to Tomcat's context.xml)
- define a resource-ref in the web.xml